# Nsxmlparser fails to detect some elements

Tags: ios, nsxmlparser

I am using NSXMLPARSER to parse a upnp soap response. While it can detect some of the elements in its delegate it cannot detect the others. I am particularly interested in extracting the upnp:albumArtURI element but failed. Anyone has any idea?

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><s:Body><u:GetPositionInfoResponse xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1"><Track>1</Track><TrackDuration>0:04:34</TrackDuration><TrackMetaData><DIDL-Lite xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:upnp="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/upnp/" xmlns:r="urn:schemas-rinconnetworks-com:metadata-1-0/" xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/DIDL-Lite/"><item id="-1" parentID="-1" restricted="true"><res protocolInfo="sonos.com-http:*:application/ogg:*" duration="0:04:34">x-sonos-http:4823265.ogg?sid=23&amp;flags=32&amp;sn=3</res><r:streamContent></r:streamContent><upnp:albumArtURI>/getaa?s=1&amp;u=x-sonos-http:4823265.ogg?sid=23&flags=32&sn=3</upnp:albumArtURI><dc:title>明年今日</dc:title><upnp:class>object.item.audioItem.musicTrack</upnp:class><dc:creator>陈奕迅</dc:creator><upnp:album>陈奕迅 广东精选 EASON CHAN CANTONESE COLLECTION</upnp:album></item></DIDL-Lite></TrackMetaData><TrackURI>x-sonos-http:4823265.ogg?sid=23&flags=32&sn=3</TrackURI><RelTime>0:00:06</RelTime><AbsTime>NOT_IMPLEMENTED</AbsTime><RelCount>2147483647</RelCount><AbsCount>2147483647</AbsCount></u:GetPositionInfoResponse></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

Comment: It's due to your xml, you have an error in. Check it with a xml validator to find the error.

Comment: Thanks. The didstartelement can detect the elements of envelope, body, getPositionInfoResponse, track, trackDuration, trackMetaData, DIDL-Lite, item & res so don't think there's error?  It just cannot detect the other elements...strange!?

Comment: Thanks. I tried to capture the error and it did have it. It's a domain 23 error and at least now I have a direction rather just stuck and don't know what to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted. Originally, I encoded the soap response to replace the '&Quot;' with '"', etc before parsing because I couldn't parse it successfully but it somehow added some errors to the response.

The reason that I couldn't parse the original response successfully is because of its complicated structure. Now I have used XMLDictionary to parse the original response first to extract the "trackMetaData" character which the "upnp:albumArtURI" being one of the elements insides then use XMLDictionary again to parse the "trackMetaData" to extract the character of the "upnp:albumArtURI".

Stuck for 2 weeks and now it resolved!!!  Happy!